# Greedy expressions in Pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to split a string like `aaa:bbb(123)` into tokens using Pyparsing.

I can do this with regular expression, but I need to do it via Pyparsing.

With `re` the solution will look like:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = 'aaa:bbb(123)'
>>> regex = '(\S+):(\S+)\((\d+)\)'
>>> re.match(regex, string).groups()
('aaa', 'bbb', '123')
```

This is clear and simple enough. The key point here is `\S+` which means "everything except whitespaces".

Now I'll try to do this with Pyparsing:

```
>>> from pyparsing import Word, Suppress, nums, printables
>>> expr = (
...     Word(printables, excludeChars=':')
...     + Suppress(':')
...     + Word(printables, excludeChars='(')
...     + Suppress('(')
...     + Word(nums)
...     + Suppress(')')
... )
>>> expr.parseString(string).asList()
['aaa', 'bbb', '123']
```

Okay, we've got the same result, but this does not look good. We've set `excludeChars` to make Pyparsing expressions to stop where we need, but this doesn't look robust. If we will have "excluded" chars in source string, same regex will work fine:

```
>>> string = 'a:aa:b(bb(123)'
>>> re.match(regex, string).groups()
('a:aa', 'b(bb', '123')
```

while Pyparsing exception will obviously break:

```
>>> expr.parseString(string).asList()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/long/path/to/pyparsing.py", line 1111, in parseString
    raise exc
ParseException: Expected W:(0123...) (at char 7), (line:1, col:8)
```

So, **the question is** how can we implement needed logic with Pyparsing?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike regex, pyparsing is purely left-to-right seeking, with no implicit lookahead.

If you want regex's lookahead and backtracking, you could just use a Regex containing your original re:

```
expr = Regex(r"(\S+):(\S+)\((\d+)\)")
print expr.parseString(string).dump()

['aaa:b(bb(123)']
```

However, I see that this returns just the whole match as a single string. If you want to be able to access the individual groups, you'll have to define them as named groups:

```
expr = Regex(r"(?P<field1>\S+):(?P<field2>\S+)\((?P<field3>\d+)\)")
print expr.parseString(string).dump()

['aaa:b(bb(123)']
- field1: aaa
- field2: b(bb
- field3: 123
```

This suggests to me that a good enhancement would be to add a constructor arg to Regex to return the results as a list of all the re groups rather than the string.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex with a look-ahead assertion:

```
from pyparsing import Word, Suppress, Regex, nums, printables

expr = (
     Word(printables, excludeChars=':')
     + Suppress(':')
     + Regex(r'\S+[^\(](?=\()')
     + Suppress('(')
     + Word(nums)
     + Suppress(')')
 )
```